# value in the kendo dropdown list is displayed as [object object]. Please find code below

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```
  var data = [
                   { text: "Black", value: "1" },
                   { text: "Orange", value: "2" },
                   { text: "Grey", value: "3" }
        ];

        $("#KendoPrefernceNameList").kendoDropDownList({
            DataTextField:"Text",
            DataValueField:"Value",                           
            dataSource : prefernceNames,
            index: 0,
            change: "prefernceNameChange",   
            //Template :"<span class=\"k - state - default\">#= Value # <img src=\"/content/images/add.png\" /></span><span>#:data.DefaultPreference#</span>",
        });
```

> The same example is there on [kendo demo site](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index). I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: It is case sensitive. Use _DataTextField:"text", DataValueField:"value"_ instead of _DataTextField:"Text", DataValueField:"Value"_

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of mistakes in this

1. dataSource should be data stored in data variable.
2. replace DataTextField and DataValueField with dataTextField and dataValueField

   ```
   $("#KendoPrefernceNameList").kendoDropDownList({
       dataTextField:"text",
       dataValueField:"value",                           
       dataSource : data
   });
   ```

   here link to working copy:
   https://jsfiddle.net/0p2gn7m6/

Comment: how would i set default value

Answer (score 0):

Your dataSource should be "data" instead of prefernceNames.
or change var to

```
var prefernceNames= [
                   { text: "Black", value: "1" },
                   { text: "Orange", value: "2" },
                   { text: "Grey", value: "3" }
        ];
```

Comment: that was by mistake, earlier it was data only. same issue

Comment: Check the data text field and value field ... it should be text and value